# Iterate through JSON object not working in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I'm trying to get data loaded from a url.

The data is given as below

```
{
    "UFs": 
    [
        {
            "Valor" : "26.348,83",
            "Fecha" : "2017-01-01"
        },
        {
            "Valor" : "26.349,68",
            "fecha" : "2017-01-02"
        }
    ]
}
```

My PHP code so far looks like this:

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);

$url = 'http://api.sbif.cl/api-sbifv3/recursos_api/uf/2017?apikey=472d79589e5bda11f1f032e62047911541c8a937&formato=json';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

foreach($obj as $item) {
    echo $item['Valor'] . "<br/>";
}
```

The problem is I'm getting blank screen everytime I tried. I also tried using curl to read the url as below:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.sbif.cl/api-sbifv3/recursos_api/uf/2017?apikey=472d79589e5bda11f1f032e62047911541c8a937&formato=json');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);

foreach($obj as $item) {
    echo $item['Valor']."<br/>";
}
```

But it doesn't work either. I guess the problem is on my for each loop, or the way I'm trying to read the array.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($obj) before your loop and post results?

Comment: Also add these 2 lines to the beginning of your script; error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are inside `UFs` object. Use the `foreach` loop this way:

```
foreach($obj['UFs'] as $item) {
    echo $item['Valor'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: @BryanGabrielMacuer Please review your error reporting settings so you don't have to ask in a forum what PHP can already tell you ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález error reporting was on, the code didnt have any errors. I was accesing the variable the wrong way.

Comment: @BryanGabrielMacuer "500 Internal Server Error" (or a blank page) means your script is throwing an error but PHP is configured to hide it from you.